# [UIView setImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance when init UISearchController

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

I'm developing an iOS application which has a feature that use `UISearchController` to provide search function for a list of countries. Up until last release, everything works fine. But now, after added some new features into the app, I encounter a weird bug that cause the application to crash. Everytime I tried to call `UISearchController(searchResultsController:nil)`, my app will crash with reason `[UIView setImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`. I traced back all the previous commits from previous release up until now but still didn't find the culprit. I would like to ask for a suggestion on how to debug this since I cannot debug into `UISearchController` initialize itself.

**NOTE** I don't provide some code snippet because I find it unnecessary, I tried several ways including call `UISearchController(searchResultsController:nil)` in another place, remove the usage of `UISearchController`, removed some suspicious extensions... to make sure that swift didn't give me another false crash report

**EDIT** My app's target version is 8.0 and I'm using swift 2.2 on XCode 7.3.1, MacOS El Capitan

**EDIT 2** I tried switching to `[[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];` but unfortunately, still got crash with the same reason.

**EDIT 3** Crash log from Crashlytics:

```
Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x181ec2db0 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x181527f80 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x181ec9c4c __methodDescriptionForSelector
3  CoreFoundation                 0x181ec6bec ___forwarding___
4  CoreFoundation                 0x181dc4c5c _CF_forwarding_prep_0
5  UIKit                          0x18710f9d0 -[UISearchBar(UISearchBarStatic) _updateMagnifyingGlassView]
6  UIKit                          0x18710d778 -[UISearchBar(UISearchBarStatic) _setupSearchField]
7  UIKit                          0x18719d2c8 -[UISearchBar searchField]
8  UIKit                          0x187114684 -[UISearchBar setPlaceholder:]
9  UIKit                          0x1879c0d3c -[UISearchController _commonInit]
10 UIKit                          0x1879c10cc -[UISearchController initWithSearchResultsController:]
11 EMCCountryPickerController     0x100bda6e8 -[EMCCountryPickerController loadView] (EMCCountryPickerController.m:136)
12 UIKit                          0x1870208ec -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired]
13 UIKit                          0x187020844 -[UIViewController view]
14 UIKit                          0x18790f450 -[_UIFullscreenPresentationController _setPresentedViewController:]
15 UIKit                          0x18737cd90 -[UIPresentationController initWithPresentedViewController:presentingViewController:]
16 UIKit                          0x1873a2af4 -[UIViewController _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:]
17 UIKit                          0x1873a5890 -[UIViewController _performCoordinatedPresentOrDismiss:animated:]
18 UIKit                          0x18711b3cc -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:]
19 UIKit                          0x193c3084c -[UIViewControllerAccessibility presentViewController:animated:completion:]
20 bluebird-ios                   0x10012e244 CountryPicker.didTapOnView() -> () (CountryPicker.swift:132)
21 bluebird-ios                   0x10012e29c @objc CountryPicker.didTapOnView() -> () (CountryPicker.swift)
22 UIKit                          0x1875b1f30 _UIGestureRecognizerSendTargetActions
23 UIKit                          0x1871c6728 _UIGestureRecognizerSendActions
24 UIKit                          0x1870537a0 -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:buttonEvent:]
25 UIKit                          0x1875b3530 ___UIGestureRecognizerUpdate_block_invoke898
26 UIKit                          0x1870124d8 _UIGestureRecognizerRemoveObjectsFromArrayAndApplyBlocks
27 UIKit                          0x18700f254 _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate
28 UIKit                          0x187051610 -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:]
29 UIKit                          0x187050c0c -[UIWindow sendEvent:]
30 UIKit                          0x18702104c -[UIApplication sendEvent:]
31 UIKit                          0x193c0545c -[UIApplicationAccessibility sendEvent:]
32 UIKit                          0x18701f628 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue
33 CoreFoundation                 0x181e7909c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
34 CoreFoundation                 0x181e78b30 __CFRunLoopDoSources0
35 CoreFoundation                 0x181e76830 __CFRunLoopRun
36 CoreFoundation                 0x181da0c50 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
37 GraphicsServices               0x183688088 GSEventRunModal
38 UIKit                          0x18708a088 UIApplicationMain
39 bluebird-ios                   0x100225a3c main (AppDelegate.swift:13)
40 libdispatch.dylib              0x18193e8b8 (Missing)
```

Answer (score 7):

**Problem Solved**

The root cause is because on `Initialize`, `UISearchBar` will call `_updateMagnifyingGlassView` which set a magnifying image to left view of its `UITextField`. In my code I have the following extension:

```
extension UITextField {
    @IBInspectable var paddingLeft: CGFloat {
        get {
            return self.leftView?.frame.width ?? 0
        } set {
            let paddingView   = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, newValue, self.frame.height))
            self.leftView     = paddingView
            self.leftViewMode = .Always
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that the property `paddingLeft` is not an optional property, which will cause `UITextField` to set `0` as default value for this property hence creating a view with width = 0 and assign to `leftView` via setter method. This cause `UISearchBar` to crash whenever `_updateMagnifyingGlassView` is called as you can see in the crash logs above.

**Conclusion**

Be careful when use extension, especially when it will modify the default behavior of existing UIKit's controls

Comment: Most relevant answer. Thanks for the solution. After using the UITextField padding extension, the app was getting crash for UISearchBar. Removed the extension and its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly put image on view in such a manner. For that follow this snippet.

```
UIView *view=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
[view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName.png"]]];
```

Or you might have drawn an outlet of `imageView` but configured your view in `Interface Builder` as a `UIView`, rather than a `UIImageView`. You have to change it to UIImageView. The crash has nothing to do with `searchReslutController`, you might be making mistake with your `imageView`.

Comment: Hi @Ishika, thanks for your response. But unfortunately, I don't think that your suggestion will work in my case. Because I tried to create a blank view controller with only one UIButton, that button hook to an action that only do one thing which is calling `UISearchController(searchResultsController:nil)`, and it still causing the crash

Comment: Then try to move your initialization code in the viewDidLoad() and check whether its works or not.